# When I use Collections.sort on an array list of my custom made objects the order is not retained

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have made some objects which have a property that is an integer, this property is dependent on another objects generated by another class. I have also made a comparator to sort them in an `ArrayList` according to that property. However, when I sort with this comparator it seems to revert back to the initial order immediately afterwards. Here is an example using dogs and breeds of the comparator I have written:

```
    public static Comparator<Breed> BreedSizeComparator = new Comparator<Breed>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Breed o1, Breed o2) {

        int pos1 = o1.getBreedSize();
        int pos2 = o2.getBreedSize();

        return pos1 - pos2;
    }
};
```

I then try to create a method that will always return the second biggest breed:

```
public static Party getSecBigBreed() {
    Collections.sort(breeds, BreedSizeComparator);
    return breeds.get(1);
}
```

When I call this though I get the breed that was at position 1 in the arraylist initially (before I did the sort). From the research I have done, it seems that it might have something to do with the fact that I put the arraylist of all the breeds created as a class variable of Breed. E.g. the class Breed is such that:

```
public class Breed {
private int size = 0;
private int type;
private static ArrayList<Breed> breeds = new ArrayList<Breed>();

public Breed(int type0) {
    type = type0;
    breeds.add(this);
}
```

I have also made a method in this breed class, to add one to size that I use each time a dog of that type is made, and another to get the breed according to its type, as well as the method to get breed size:

```
public void increaseSize() {
    this.Size++;
}

public static Breed getBreed(int type0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < breeds.size(); i++) {
         if(type0 = breeds.get(i).type) {
              return breeds.get(i);
         }
    }
}

public int getBreedSize() {
    return size;
}
```

Here is my dog class:

```
public class Dog {
private int type;
private int dogNumber;
private static ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

public Dog(int type0) {
    type = type0;
    getBreed(type).increaseSize();
}
```

Can't really figure out why when I sort the `ArrayList` breeds according to the size of the breed, it then reverts back to the original ordering.

Comment: "`if(type0 = breeds.get(i).type) {`" and a lack of return after the loop means this code doesn't compile. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It's really difficult to follow your code and very hard to isolate the issue. I'd suggest that you use a debugger and step through the code to find the culprit. If the order indeed falls back (`private static ArrayList<Breed> breeds` looks like the smelly candidate to watch here, especially when you have many instances of Dog/Breed), you'd immediately see it stepping through.

Answer (score 1):

Still looking through everything but one thing stood out to me:

```
    public static Comparator<Breed> BreedSizeComparator = new Comparator<Breed>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Breed o1, Breed o2) {

        int pos1 = o1.getBreedSize();
        int pos2 = o2.getBreedSize();

        return pos1 - pos2;
    }
};
```

I don't know what the values of these are but it's important to note how compare works:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second. In the foregoing description, the
>   notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function,
>   which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the
>   value of expression is negative, zero or positive.

So if pos1 and pos2 are both negative, positive, or equal, you may see unexpected or even no movement within the list

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
public static Comparator<Breed> BreedSizeComparator = new Comparator<Breed>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Breed o1, Breed o2) {

        int pos1 = o1.getBreedSize();
        int pos2 = o2.getBreedSize();

        if (pos1 > pos2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (pos2 > pos1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT:
as Thomas Jungblut pointed out, an even simpler solution would be:

```
public static Comparator<Breed> BreedSizeComparator = new Comparator<Breed>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Breed o1, Breed o2) {

        int pos1 = o1.getBreedSize();
        int pos2 = o2.getBreedSize();

        return Integer.valueOf(pos1).compareTo(pos2);
    }
};
```

what 'compareTo' does is return a 0 if both values are equal, a negative value if the first argument is less than the second, and a positive value if the first argument is greater than the second.

Comment: `Integer.compare(o1.getBreedSize(), o2.getBreedSize())` makes it even easier. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)

Comment: very true!  I just wanted to show a scenario showing how the values are returned.  I'll update my answer

Comment: sure no doubts! If you want to seek the easiest to digest, using lambdas you could write `Collections.sort(breeds, (l, r) -> Integer.compare(l.getBreedSize(), r.getBreedSize()));` Autoboxing should save you the `valueOf` calls.

Comment: I'm an android dev and the company I work for is VERY strict regarding 3rd party libraries (like retrolamda).  So lamdas don't exist in my life :P

Comment: The comparator I wrote works fine, but it was giving me ascending order when I needed descending order.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator needed to be the other way around:

```
public static Comparator<Breed> BreedSizeComparator = new Comparator<Breed>() {
@Override
public int compare(Breed o1, Breed o2) {

    int pos1 = o1.getBreedSize();
    int pos2 = o2.getBreedSize();

    //return pos1 - pos2;

    //ArrayList needs to be in descending order
    return pos1 - pos2;
}
};
```